# wait.until(ExpectedCondition) generating error

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, wait

After upgrading to selenium Java 3.8.1 the `wait.until(ExpectedCondition)` has started giving error message.

For the following piece of code

```
WebElement framei = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dlgModal_IFrame']")));       
    driver.switchTo().frame(framei);
    WebElement AcceptRadioButton=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='RblStatus']/tbody/tr[1]/td/label")));
    AcceptRadioButton.click();
```

The following error is given:

```
Type The method until(Function<? super WebDriver,V>) in the type FluentWait<WebDriver> is not applicable for the arguments (ExpectedCondition<WebElement>)
```

I tried to resolve the following issue by removing the Selenium java version 3.8.1 of

Answer (score 1):

Same problem as you but not so sure about Eugene S answer I search in sources of selenium-java 2.53.1 and 3.8.1 to see what was different between FluentWait class. Here are until fonctions of the different version:

2.53.1 :

```
  public void until(final Predicate<T> isTrue) {
    until(new Function<T, Boolean>() {
      public Boolean apply(T input) {
        return isTrue.apply(input);
      }

      public String toString() {
        return isTrue.toString();
      }
    });
  }
```

OR

```
  public <V> V until(Function<? super T, V> isTrue) {
    long end = clock.laterBy(timeout.in(MILLISECONDS));
    Throwable lastException = null;
    while (true) {
      try {
        V value = isTrue.apply(input);
        if (value != null && Boolean.class.equals(value.getClass())) {
          if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(value)) {
            return value;
          }
        } else if (value != null) {
          return value;
        }
      } catch (Throwable e) {
        lastException = propagateIfNotIgnored(e);
      }

  // Check the timeout after evaluating the function to ensure conditions
  // with a zero timeout can succeed.
      if (!clock.isNowBefore(end)) {
        String message = messageSupplier != null ?
            messageSupplier.get() : null;

        String toAppend = message == null ?
            " waiting for " + isTrue.toString() : ": " + message;

        String timeoutMessage = String.format("Timed out after %d seconds%s",
            timeout.in(SECONDS), toAppend);
        throw timeoutException(timeoutMessage, lastException);
      }

      try {
        sleeper.sleep(interval);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        throw new WebDriverException(e);
      }
    }
  }
```

AND IN 3.8.1:

```
  public <V> V until(Function<? super T, V> isTrue) {
    long end = clock.laterBy(timeout.in(MILLISECONDS));
    Throwable lastException;
    while (true) {
      try {
        V value = isTrue.apply(input);
        if (value != null && (Boolean.class != value.getClass() || Boolean.TRUE.equals(value))) {
          return value;
        }

    // Clear the last exception; if another retry or timeout exception would
    // be caused by a false or null value, the last exception is not the
    // cause of the timeout.
        lastException = null;
      } catch (Throwable e) {
        lastException = propagateIfNotIgnored(e);
      }

  // Check the timeout after evaluating the function to ensure conditions
  // with a zero timeout can succeed.
      if (!clock.isNowBefore(end)) {
        String message = messageSupplier != null ?
            messageSupplier.get() : null;

        String timeoutMessage = String.format(
            "Expected condition failed: %s (tried for %d second(s) with %s interval)",
            message == null ? "waiting for " + isTrue : message,
            timeout.in(SECONDS), interval);
        throw timeoutException(timeoutMessage, lastException);
      }

      try {
        sleeper.sleep(interval);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        throw new WebDriverException(e);
      }
    }
  }
```

I don't see any difference between the three functions arguments but the project I work on did not return me any error with 2.53.1 version but with 3.8.1 I have the same error than Akhil.

Answer (score 0):

As it says in the error message:

```
FluentWait<WebDriver> is not applicable for the arguments (ExpectedCondition<WebElement>)
```

Starting from Selenium 3, `until` method declaration now looks like this:

```
public <V> V until(Function<? super T, V> isTrue)
```

where `Function` is:

```
public interface Function<T, R>
```

So it has been converted to use Java 8 functional interface. You will need to rewrite your expected conditions accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

As per best practices we must try to switch to a `<iframe>` with proper `WebDriverWait` as follows :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dlgModal_IFrame']")));
```